# Height and width as percentage or another solution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image: View 1][image: View2]

What I have so far 
[image]

I started by using wrap content and added padding between buttons, but that was a problem because on some phones it would take only half the screen so I ended up using weights. My first problem is that the buttons on page 1 have 0.5 of the screen size and a padding between them of 15dp so each button has 0.5*screensize/7. If I'll do the same for the second view, the buttons will have the height 0.5*screensize/3(therefore bigger heights). I also don't know how to push the 'Post it' button at the bottom of the page by using weights. The second problem is that I want to use weights for width as well(so far my weight is fixed for most of them), but that might lead to some performance issue(I'll use way too many linear layouts) as this guys is saying here 
[Android XML: Percentage Height and width to create unique layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527703/android-xml-percentage-height-and-width-to-create-unique-layout).

My code for the view1 picture that I coded in Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gradientf1"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Title1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Title2"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/first" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
                android:background="@drawable/second" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/third" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Button5"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Button6"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next step"
            android:background="@drawable/nxtbtn"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/nxtbtn"
            android:text="Post it"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any other way of coding those 2 images in android ? And as you can see I don't have yet the + at the end of the button. That + will turn in a approved('tick' sign) once the users completes the data that will be opened by clicking the button(I haven t done any of those fragments yet).*I'm sorry for the size of the images, but I couldn t find how to resize them*

Update: What I'm trying to do is have the same look on all phones. I thought I can do this by using weight and linear layouts, but it's quite tricky.

Comment: You should look at android PercentageLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: That seems like a nice approach, but I would still have to use a fixed width and it's still going to look different on every screen. On some screens it might go off the screen.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want the user to be able to add more buttons by pressing the + icon, right? if so, you should really consider using a ScrollView

Comment: No, the + buttons shows only that the user hasn't introduced the information in the fragment that the button will open

Comment: Once the information is introduced, the + will transform in a 'tick' sign

Comment: Alright, so let's say you have 6 buttons. what you expect to happen when the device is in landscape mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102003/discussion-between-much-overflow-and-bogdan-daniel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/C8oaLunpEEj. Google has a new support library which will achieve this without using weights. It's exactly what I needed. You just have to add it to gradle `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'` and start using it like

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

If android complains about layout_height/width just add them, it won't modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Use a `RelativeLayout` for the main container, so you can align the "Post it" button to the bottom with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and the "Button-Container" as you like (centered etc).

2) For better testing, you should use a style for your buttons, like:

in `/res/values/styles.xml`:

```
   <style name="CustomButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        etc...
    </style>
```

in your layout:

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/CustomButton"/>
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at the relative layout for that, but my main problem are the buttons that should be the same height on all pages. I worked it out for the View1, but as I said there if I do the same for View2 they won't have the same weight. I already have a style for buttons's background, I'll add one for their style too, but again that's not the problem.

Comment: Ah ok. I wouldn't recommend setting the height through vertical weight. Just set them to wrap_content or a static height, and leave them. Maybe I don't get the problem though.

Comment: If I set it on wrap_content/static height I'm having the following problem. On nexus 4 it might look good(taking all screen), but on s6 edge+ it's going to take only 4/5 of the screen. I want to have the same look on all screens, or at least close.